# Can't connect to RDS proxy via EC2 instance

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-rds, amazon-rds-proxy

Currently been trying to connect to RDS proxy via a centos EC2 instance, however I keep getting this error:

> psql: FATAL:  This RDS proxy has no credentials for the role centos. Check the credentials for this role and try again.

I am assuming that I have to assign some type of role to the EC2 to access the proxy? Apologies for the minimal detail.

Comment: What is "role centos"?

Answer (score 0):

Can your EC2 instance connect to RDS instance without proxy? RDS proxy doesn't require any IAM Role [image: RDS Proxy Role]

If you try to find Proxy permissions in IAM Role you can't find any. If IAM Role is already attached then make sure that your Security Group is properly configured. You have to open port from your instance to DB.

Answer (score 0):

*You're not alone, I hate permissions too*

In my case I didn't have the IAM policy correctly set up to read the connection secrets from Secrets Manager.

So this is what you need:

1. A user with access your database
2. Have that user's credentials in Secrets Manager (must be created as **Credentials for Amazon RDS database**)
3. Set up a policy that will have access to this secret and the information about the KMS key that can be used to decrypt the secret (this is what I was missing, see example below)
4. An IAM role with that policy
5. The IAM role is assigned to the proxy

The first part of the policy is which secret, the second part is the key to decrypt it:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "secretsmanager:GetSecretValue",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-east-2:account_id:secret:secret_name_1",
                "arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-east-2:account_id:secret:secret_name_2"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "kms:Decrypt",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:kms:us-east-2:account_id:key/key_id",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "kms:ViaService": "secretsmanager.us-east-2.amazonaws.com"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

More details in this guide:

[Setting up AWS Identity and Access Management (IAM) policies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/rds-proxy-setup.html#rds-proxy-iam-setup)

I also found this troubleshooting guide really helpful:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/rds-proxy.troubleshooting.html